# show sum of relational table attribute value in yii2 gridview

Tags: gridview, yii2

I have 2 DB tables with a 1-n relationship: task and activities. Task can have N activities associated, and each activity contains a "hours" attribute.
In the grid view of "Tasks", for each entry, I want to show the sum of the "hours" of the related activities. Is it possible?

Thank you

Alessandro

Answer (score 0):

You may add a getter to your model:

```
public function getActivityHourSum()
{
    return $this->getActivities()->sum('hours');
}
```

and than in the GridView:

```
'columns' => [
    ...
    'activityHourSum',
    ...
]
```

This way is the simplest but also the less productive one.
The other way is to add $activityHourSum attribute to a model class and populate its value in the search method using joined relation table.